# How to sort Time/Date output?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sort

Let's have

```
16:00_17/06/2022
12:31_10/05/2022
10:34_07/03/2023
11:17_12/04/2022
12:37_10/05/2022
```

I would like to sort this output in ascending order to get this:

```
11:17_12/04/2022
12:31_10/05/2022
12:37_10/05/2022
16:00_17/06/2022
10:34_07/03/2023
```

I tried `sort -t '_' -k2 -k1` and `sort -t '/' -k3 -k2 -k1` but I already get a disorganized arrangement.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Thank you.

Comment: What about this: cat list  | tr _ / | sort -t/ -n -k4 -k3 -k2 -k1 | sed s@/@_@

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assuming your input format is** `hour:minute_day-of-month/month/year`, then one convenient option might be to use `dsort` from the `dateutils` package:

```
$ dateutils.dsort --input-format='%H:%M_%d/%m/%Y' dates
11:17_12/04/2022
12:31_10/05/2022
12:37_10/05/2022
16:00_17/06/2022
10:34_07/03/2023
```

If you need to do it with plain GNU `sort`, then provided the fields have fixed width then you can do so using the extended `F.C` (field.character) form of key definition to "split" the first `/`-delimited field into `H:M` and `d` and sort on the latter first, ex.

```
sort -t/ -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1.7,1.8 -k1.1,1.5 dates
```

Comment: The last option (`-k1,1`) will sort in HH,MM,DD order of the same month, not in DD,HH,MM.

Comment: Ah... so the subfield after the `_` is a day number, not seconds? The OP doesn't make that clear.

Comment: @FedKad updated now